# Develop a Grafana plugin with react without using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, plugins, grafana

I am going to develop a custom plugin for Grafana. As far as I know, it must be developed using React and Typescript. I am going to use deck.gl in the plugin but deck.gl do not support Typescript at the moment. Although there are some unofficial packages to do so, I have faced some difficulties to use them (they are not update and the not support all types).

So, I am relatively new to JS and typescript. I would like to know is there any way to develop a Grafana plugin without using typescript (using pure React instead)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I search, it is possible to do so but it is not reasonable (nobody has suggested that). My biggest problem with typescript is using libraries without type definitions. I tried to ignore definitions and config typescript to ignore these types, and it solved my problem (it was a tricky one!).